# What are examples of utilities for checking schemes and paths in Java?

Tags: java

I don't want to copy-paste a code like this when checking a scheme for validity

```
Pattern.matches("[a-z]+://", scheme)
```

or code like this to check a path (don't nitpick, I realize it's simplified)

```
Pattern.matches("/[A-Za-z\\d-]+", path);
```

I'm sure I don't need to write such a utility muself because I bet someone already did

What are examples of utilities for checking schemes and paths in Java? Standard libraries would be perfect, but something from, for example, Spring or Apache Commons would suffice too

Here's approximately what I want:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UriValidator {
    public static void requireValidPath(String docPath) {
        boolean matchesPathPattern = isValidPath(docPath);
        if (!matchesPathPattern) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid path: " + docPath);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidPath(String path) {
        return Pattern.matches("/[^?#]+[^/?#]", path);
    }

    public static void requireValidScheme(String scheme) {
        boolean matchesSchemePattern = isValidScheme(scheme);
        if (!matchesSchemePattern) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid scheme: " + scheme);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidScheme(String scheme) {
        return Pattern.matches("[A-Za-z][A-Za-z+.-]+://", scheme);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html?

Comment: @k314159 thank you, it's close. However, it doesn't have the `require*()` methods and also its methods are not static so I have to create an instance first